# DVI-I - Single Link vs Dual Link

Tags: display, dvi, vga

I have two DVI-I to VGA adapters yet each one is different. From what I can tell one is a single link and the other a dual link DVI-I adapter.

I read some about this on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface) but I get lost in the technical details between single and dual link DVI. Can someone exaplain what the difference is and is one better to use over the other? (Keep in mind I am running on an older VGA monitor)

Here are a couple images, one a diagram between Single and Dual and then one of the actual adapters.

[image: Diagram Showing the difference between Single amd Dual Link DVI-I] [image: Photo showing the two DVI adapters]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single-link and Dual-link only apply to the digital connection, not the analog VGA connector.  See the [DVI to VGA pin conversion](http://www.instructables.com/community/DVI-to-VGA-Conversion-on-a-Budget/).

There shouldn't be any difference between the adapters.  I don't know why one has all the pins in it when it doesn't need them.

Comment: The extra pins are for dual link which gives higher resolution - see the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a bit more searching and I came across this:

> DVI dual link as the name implies has more conductors than the DVI single link for transmitting signal. Single link DVI supports a maximum bandwidth of 165 MHz (1920 x 1080 at 60 Hz, 1280 x 1024 at 85 Hz) and utilizes 12 of the 24 available pins. Dual link DVI utilizes all 24 available pins and supports 2x 165 MHz maximum bandwidth (2048 x 1536 at 60 Hz, 1920 x 1080 at 85 Hz).

Comment: You might want to add this as an edit to your question