# How do I know if my PC is dual link DVI?

Tags: dvi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DVI-I - Single Link vs Dual Link](https://superuser.com/questions/362878/dvi-i-single-link-vs-dual-link)

How do I know if my Dell Latitude E6420 has dual link DVI? It has a VGA output but the docking station has two DVI outputs?

Is there a VGA to Dual Link DVI adapter?

Is Dual Link DVI a computer spec or a cable feature?

[image]

Comment: It's a function of the port (and by extension, the video adapter) itself.  The only way to be 100% sure is to look up the exact specs on the hardware in question.  (Dual-link does have more pins but some single-link ports have the holes for those pins, just not connected to anything, so visual inspection isn't sufficient.)

Answer (score 1):

The product you are looking at appears to be Dell part number [430-3113](http://accessories.dell.com/sna/products/Docking/productdetail.aspx?c=ca&l=en&s=dhs&cs=cadhs1&sku=430-3113&~ck=baynoteSearch&baynote_bnrank=2&baynote_irrank=0). Although it is not clear, it appears that this docking port offers only a single-link DVI connector. The higher end docking port, Dell part number [430-3114](http://accessories.dell.com/sna/products/Docking/productdetail.aspx?c=ca&l=en&s=dhs&cs=cadhs1&sku=430-3114&~ck=baynoteSearch&baynote_bnrank=4&baynote_irrank=0), specifically lists that it supports 2560x1600 via the display ports. This implies that the included DVI connectors are still single-link, but at least you now would be able to run the higher resolution through a display port connection, assuming your monitor can support that.

Comment: A Dell Sales Rep said they're Dual Link. I'm not sure if he's a reliable source though...

Comment: Many years later I have tried it, and the ports are single-link only.  They appear to behave the same way as plugging a passive single-link DisplayPort to DVI adapter into the DisplayPort connectors.  1920x1200 max resolution.  You definitely need to use native DisplayPort to go higher than this (with a Latitude E7440, 4K@30Hz seems to be the DP limit).